# What Is the Mouse Movement Resolution on the Screen

Tags: windows, resolution

This question is just for the sake of my inherent curiosity. I wonder, by what resolution does the mouse move on the screen? Are we actually moving the cursor along every single pixel on the screen? Is the cursor programmed to skip some while moving the mouse?

To clarify, imagine that there is a 1-pixel icon on my Windows desktop and I only want to select it without any other objects around it. Could this be accomplished?

Thank you

Comment: Resolution can be down to the pixel if you have a steady hand.  It's easier with a (big) trackball.  This can easily be verified with a drawing or CAD program.

Comment: The mouse generates signals based on its movement; so many signals per inch of movement.  The driver translates the signals to screen distance, which doesn't equal mouse distance.  The translation is a sensitivity setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder, by what resolution does the mouse move on the screen?

It depends on the resolution of the mouse. The higher the dpi (dots per inch) the more accurate you can work.

> Is the cursor programmed to skip some while moving the mouse?

The polling rate is the rate the computer asks (or mouse reports) the current position of the mouse. So when you make a large quick move with your mouse the computer cursor will skip pixels.

> To clarify, imagine that there is a 1-pixel icon on my Windows desktop
>   and I only want to select it without any other objects around it.
>   Could this be accomplished?

If your motor skills are up to it, absolutely.

[Here's](https://www.howtogeek.com/182702/mouse-dpi-and-polling-rates-explained-do-they-matter-for-gaming/) a deeper explanation article about mouse dbi and polling rate.

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder, by what resolution does the mouse move on the screen? Are we actually moving the cursor along every single pixel on the screen?

Yes. It depends on the currently selected display resolution, of course, not the display’s “native” resolution.

> To clarify, imagine that there is a 1-pixel icon on my Windows desktop and I only want to select it without any other objects around it. Could this be accomplished?

Yes, absolutely. You need a decent mouse and a low enough sensitivity setting though.